# Azure table storage with large entity sizes

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

A couple of questions that I can't find any answers to. Hope someone can help:

1. I will be using entity sizes of almost 1MB. I can't find any information on read latency for these large entity sizes. Is there anyone out there that has any information on this.
2. Is there any way to determine how much space is used for a row in Azure table storage. Any API for this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If most of our entities are large, then it somehow [defeats the purpose of Table Storage](http://vermorel.com/journal/2009/9/17/table-storage-or-the-100x-cost-factor.html) in the first place. Indeed, you will only be able to retrieve update them 4 by 4 max, as entity transactions are limited to 4MB.

You can get many useful measurements on the [AzureScope project](http://azurescope.cloudapp.net/) concerning the Table Storage, but also the other storage services of Azure.

Then, if you want to accurately check the weight of your rows, just use Fiddler to intercept your web requests, and directly look at the XML being produced.

Comment: AzureScope project seems to max out at 4KB when showing latency. I wonder why they didn't do larger sizes as the max is 1MB. I wish I could use Fiddler but my requests are from table-storage to the internal VM and fiddler can't really help with that unless maybe if I load fiddler on the VM.